# Running JUnit through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

I run my JUnit tests through Eclipse (Helios, 1.3.0) through an ant build file and an external ant builder. I was wondering if it's possible to use Eclipes's JUnit UI when running them so that I can see the 'green' or 'red' bar in there instead of seeing success/failure messages in the console. Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must run your tests via ant, then there is no direct way to see the progress in the JUnit view.  However, if you are using the JUnit ant task and set the output format of your test results to `xml` :

Then, you can open this file up in the JUnit window.  Click on the button on the far right and select `Import`.  Then navigate to the file you want to open:
[image: JUnit View in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

If you have JUnit reference for a project, I think you can right click on a project and select `Run As > JUnit Test` and that will run all the tests in the Project. Check out [this post](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_java_development_guide/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/eclipse_java_qs-junit.htm)

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. My Eclipse doesn't have a JUnit reference for them. I'm also using Cobertura through ant build file and don't want to miss on generating coverage reports.

Comment: @shrini1000 you could try http://www.eclemma.org/ for code coverage. it's more visual than cobertura reports.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse: Writing and running JUnit tests](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-junit.htm)

Comment: @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu: thanks for your reply; but this is not what I'm looking for. The reason I'm running JUnit test cases through ant builder is so I won't have to create and maintain my own test suites. I just use '<batchtest>' and point it to '*Test.java' from my tests folder, and all tests get automatically run. I just want to see the result in Eclipse JUnit UI instead of in its console.